# Remove the rows with duplicate entries in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df like this:

```
Num <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5)
ID <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C","D","E")
dff <- data.frame(Num,ID)
```

I am trying to remove any rows that have duplicate entries. I am doing this way

```
dff1 <- dff[!duplicated(dff[,1]),]
```

I get the output

```
  Num ID
1   1  A
4   2  A
6   3  C
7   4  D
8   5  E
```

But my desired output is

```
  Num ID
6   3  C
7   4  D
8   5  E
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: You are 'missing' that duplicated returns a vector that is 'F' for the first occurence of an element, and T for each occurence after that.

Comment: `dff[!(dff$Num %in% dff$Num[duplicated(dff$Num)]),]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
dff[dff$Num %in% as.numeric(names(table(dff$Num)==1)[table(dff$Num)==1]),]
  Num ID
6   3  C
7   4  D
8   5  E
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dff %>% group_by(Num) %>% filter(n()==1)
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: Num

  Num ID
1   3  C
2   4  D
3   5  E
```

Comment: Nice dplyr solution. I like this. Thanks @DatamineR

Comment: @Sharath you are welcome :-)